# Google map setting marker using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, doctype

I have started working on Google maps recently.What I have done till now is to get current location(position) on Google map.It works fine and displays the current position successfully. 
But when I place the "!DOCTYPE html" tag in the very first line of my html code, the map is not displayed.

Also, I replaced the "%" in div tags "style" attribute with the "px" (pixels) when I used the "!DOCTYPE html" tag in my document, but it didn't worked.

I am using both Google Chrome (version 21.0.1180.41) and Firefox (version 14.0b12) web browsers to display the map, but it doesn't work for any of them.
What may be the possible reasons? Please answer.
Thanks!

Comment: sounds like a problem using % sized divs,  really not enough information to tell for sure.  Take a look at [Mike Williams' v2 tutorial page on percentage sized divs (Part 20 Using a percentage height for the map div)](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm), see if it helps (the concept is the same for the v3 API).  If not, post a link to a map that exhibits the problem or a jsfiddle that does.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for your help. That really worked. Setting the <html> and <body> tags' styles to 100% solved my problem.
Thanks once again for your help.